# Javascript message not displaying

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am trying to insert data into a database for a user's profile picture.The function is working properly but the issue is the message to notify the user is not displaying anything.I have attached the code below for the controler as i am using code igniter.

```
function fresherImageStore()  
{  
    if (isset($_FILES["image_file"]["name"]))  
    {  
        $user = $this->session->userdata('fresher_id');
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/fresherimages';  
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';  
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);  

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image_file'))  
        {  
            $error =  $this->upload->display_errors(); 
            echo json_encode(array('msg' => $error, 'success' => false));
        }  
        else 
        {  
            $user = $this->session->userdata('fresher_id');
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $data1 = array(
                'user' => $user,
                'name' => $data['upload_data']['file_name']
            );  
            $query = $this->db->get_where('images',array('user'=>$user));

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                $this->db->set('name',$data['upload_data']['file_name'])
                    ->where('user',$user)
                    ->update('images');        
                $arr = array('msg' => 'Your image has been uploaded successfully', 'success' => true);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->insert('images',$data1);
                $getId = $this->db->insert_id();

                $arr = array('msg' => 'Image has not uploaded successfully', 'success' => false);

                if ($getId) {
                    $arr = array('msg' => 'Image has been uploaded successfully', 'success' => true);
                }
                echo json_encode($arr);
            }  
        }  
    }
}
```

then this is the html

```
 <form method="POST" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
 <div class="col-md-7">
   <h3> Upload your photo</h3></br>
    <div id="divMsg" class="alert alert-success" style="display: none">
     <span id="ms"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="file" name="image_file" multiple="true" accept="image/*" id="finput" onchange="readURL(this);"></br></br>
     <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-5"></div>
```

and finally the jquery function

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#upload_form').on('submit', function(e){  
       e.preventDefault();  
       if($('#image_file').val() == '')  
       {  
            alert("Please Select the File");  
       }  
       else 
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/seekerImageStore",   
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:new FormData(this),  
                 contentType: false,  
                 cache: false,  
                 processData:false,  
                 dataType: "json",
                 success:function(res)  
                 {  

                    console.log(res.success);
                    if(res.success == true){
                     $('#blah').attr('src','//www.tutsmake.com/ajax-image-upload-with-preview-in-codeigniter/');   
                     $('#msg').html(res.msg1);   
                     $('#divMsg').show();   
                    }
                    else if(res.success == false){
                      $('#msg').html(res.msg); 
                      $('#divMsg').show(); 
                    }
                    setTimeout(function(){
                     $('#msg').html('');
                     $('#divMsg').hide(); 
                    }, 3000);
                 }  
            });  
       }  
  });
```

Comment: What does `console.log(res.success);` show you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code is trying to append the message on an element with id `msg` but the `span` tag where the message is supposed to go is called `ms`.

If you look in your browser's console, you'll see the error. You are pointing to a non-existing ID

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

you are not getting any message on "success", because you are not sending any json when that case is met.

just take the take `echo json_encode($arr);` out of the nested if/**else**:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    $this->db->set('name',$data['upload_data']['file_name'])
        ->where('user',$user)
        ->update('images');        
    $arr = array('msg' => 'Your image has been uploaded successfully', 'success' => true);
}
else
{
    $this->db->insert('images',$data1);
    $getId = $this->db->insert_id();

    $arr = array('msg' => 'Image has not uploaded successfully', 'success' => false);

    if ($getId) {
        $arr = array('msg' => 'Image has been uploaded successfully', 'success' => true);
    }   
}  
echo json_encode($arr);
```

then in your view (ajax sucess) you can output the message like this:

```
$('#divMsg').show().find('span').html(res.msg);
```